# how to update FieldStorageDefinition in a hook update?

Tags: 8, entities, feeds

This is a feeds [module related issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3055560). An entity update that  started to cause errors on 8.7.x a[fter the removal of automatic entity update](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742). Originally an entity definition needed to be updated using `entup` but was not. And after upgrading to 8.7 this started to cause fatal errors. So now I have to force update it:

In summary:

```
$field_storage_definition = $entity_definition_update_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('config', 'feeds_feed');
```

returns an object:

```
Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition Object
(
    [type:protected] => feeds_serialized
....
```

I need to update this object so `[type:protected] => map` instead.

For what's it's worth, it is also possible to uninstall the module and re-install it but I am now just curious on how to update this object in a hook_update.